# Gradle How to exclude files from apk

Tags: android, gradle

I store my keystore at my assets directory. How can exclude it in the build to create the .apk?

I tried in that way but still there:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
            ...
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            ...
            exclude 'assets/keystore'
    }
}
```

It exclude the `LICENSE.txt` but not the `keystore`

Answer (score 3):

Try with next:

```
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    //if (variant.name.contains('Release')) { // exclude source and sourcemap from release builds
    def rmkeystore = task("delete${variant.name}.rmkeystore", type: Delete) {
        delete "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}/keystore"
    }
    variant.mergeAssets.finalizedBy rmkeystore
    //}
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168827/717267