# Adding extra files to .apk

Tags: android, apk

I want to distribute my game for android, linux and windows in a single apk. So, I want to add linux and windows executables in the outermost folder in apk (so that users can easily reach them). Is that possible? They need not to be installed when somebody installs the app in android.

Answer (score 1):

An APK is a zip file so you can add new files to it using a tool like 7-zip.

To avoid them being installed you can exclude them using the gradle script:

See this question for more info: [Gradle How to exclude files from apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885763/gradle-how-to-exclude-files-from-apk)